# PostgreSQL Selecting The Closest Previous Month of June

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to write a piece for a query that grabs the closest, past June 1st.  For example, today is 10/2/2018.  If I run the query today, I need it to use the date 6/1/2018.  If I run it on 5/29/2019, it still needs to grab 6/1/2018.  If I run it on 6/2/2019, it should then grab 6/1/2019.  If I run it on 6/2/2022, it should then grab 6/1/2022 and so on.

I believe I need to start with something like this:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW())>=6 THEN 'CURRENT' ELSE 'RF LAST' END AS X
 --If month is greater than or equal to 6, you are in the CURRENT YEAR (7/1/CURRENT YEAR)
 --If month is less than 6, then reference back to the last year (YEAR MINUS ONE)
```

And I believe I need to truncate the date then perform an operation.  I am unsure of which approach to take (if I should be adding a year to a timestamp such as '6/1/1900', or if I should try to disassemble the date parts to perform an operation.  I keep getting errors in my attempts such as "operator does not exist".  Things I have tried include:

```
 SELECT (CURRENT_DATE- (CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '7 months'))
 --This does not work as it just gives me a count of days.

 SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('month',NOW())+TIMESTAMP'1900-01-01 00:00:00')
 --Variations of this just don't work and generally error out.
```

Comment: nb: less than 10% of the world's population understands mm/dd/yyyy (a truly weird format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case expression to determine if you need to use the current year, or, the previous year (months 1 to 5)

```
case when extract(month from current_date) >= 6 then 0 else -1 end
```

then add that to the year extracted from current_date, e.g. using `to_date()`

```
select to_Date('06' || (extract(year from current_date)::int + case when extract(month from current_date) >= 6 then 0 else -1 end)::varchar, 'mmYYYY');
```

You could also use `make_date(year int, month int, day int)` in postgres 9.4+

```
select make_date(extract(year from current_date) + case when extract(month from current_date) >= 6 then 0 else -1 end, 6, 1) ;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This appeared to do exactly what I needed it to do once I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

> If month lower than 6, trunc year and minus 6 months.
>   Else trunc year and add 6 months.

```
set datestyle to SQL,MDY;

select 
case when (extract( month from (date::date)))<6 then date_trunc('year',date)-'6 month'::interval 
else date_trunc('year',date)+'6 months'::interval 
end as closest_prev_june,
another_column,
another_column2
from mytable;
```

But format is default and supposed you have a column that named date.

> If you want to do this with now(), change date columns with now()
>   function.

Comment: Thank you.  This is good information, however, unfortunately this one errored out in my particular script once I tried to feed the date back into another select.

Comment: Edited answer for MDY format. `set datestyle` works for session does not effect globally. If you want to change it globally, `alter system set datestyle to SQL,MDY;` and reload server.